# react - correct way to rerender an element

Tags: reactjs

I am a novice in react and I wanted to know how to re-render an element. In the following example, I have a datepicker and a button which I want to disable if the date is already in a certain array.

```
export const Home = (props: IHomeProp) => {
  const { dateArr } = props;
  const [allowRes, setallowRes] = useState(true);

  function allowReservation(date2check) {
    dateArr.forEach(element => {
      if (element.beginDate === date2check) {
        setallowRes(false);
        return;
      }
    });
    setallowRes(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker onChange={date => allowReservation(date)}/>
      <span>
        {allowRes ? (
          <Button color="success"> New Reservation </Button>
        ) : (
          <Button color="success" disabled> New Reservation </Button>
        )}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can I make it that when `allowRes` changes, the `Button` part gets re-rendered?

Also, is it possible to execute `allowReservation` once when the page is loaded before `Button` gets rendered?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are already setting the default state when you call `useState`, are you saying you want to change it again once the page is loaded? React components are setup to re-render when state changes, are you saying this currently doesn't work? Can you create an small working example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: This does not work. I did some debugging and apparently ` setallowRes(false);` inside the `if` does not change the state of `allowRes` to `false`. Why does this happen? Logs inside the if get executed though.

Comment: are you _sure_ it's not working? Can you log `allowRes` just before you render to verify that it is indeed not changing? If you are saying that doesn't work then that's a major problem as this is fundamental to how React Hooks work.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The problem was the last line inside the function `setallowRes(true);`. Even though I had a return inside the forEach, this line still got executed. Your certainty that it was not a react problem made me look for other issues in the code.

Comment: ah of course, good spot. However, looking at your code I think this could certainly be done a bit better, would you be interested in an improvement answer? I could encorporate the original problem as well